# How is power affected on a step-up transformer, does it change?

Tags: led, power, transformer

Ok here is what I have found so far about Step up and step down transformers:

1. Step down transformers change a high voltage/low current, to low voltage/high current.
2. Step up transformers change a low voltage/high current, to high voltage/low current.

What about power?

From what I can see, power in a transformer will stay the same based on the power equation power shouldn't change from one side of the coils to the other side.  Does the power stay the same? Can power be increased with a transformer? If not, can power be increased somehow?

If power does not change, then how can an 11W LED light put out 50w of power based on power equation and transformers performance? Or is this something totally different?

Comment: Power isn't something that you can create or drum-up at will. You may find that an 11W LED outputs the equivalent light of a 50W regular filament lightbulb.

Comment: You can never create energy, so no, power can not be increased in any way.

Comment: @Gunnish: Reducing resistance increases power by drawing more energy from the battery, so it's not unreasonable to assume that transformers change the power likewise without creating energy. That's how I always assumed phone chargers and suchlike worked.

Answer (score 5):

**1. Second question first:**

> If power does not change, then how can an 11W LED light put out 50w of power based on power equation and transformers performance?

It is often claimed that an eg LED light will out as much light as much light as a 50W incandescent lightbulb. This relates to the electrical to light power (lumens) conversion efficiency - related mainly but not solely to the absolute power levels.

- LED lights are more efficient at producing visible light than incandescent bulbs - they produce more visible light energy out for a given amount of electrical input power. The key word here is **visible**. An incandescent bulb converts almost 100% of its input energy to electromagnetic energy BUT most of this is in the infrared spectrum where the human eye sees little or none of it. This is the main factor in the difference in effective light outputs.
- Perceived brightness depends on the human eye's sensitivity and many LED lights make light which is closer to the most sensitive wavelength of the human eye than incandescent lights do. This is a smaller but significant part of the difference.
- LED lights can have their beam shape more closely tailored to their application so may be able to place more of their light on the target surface,Incandescent bulbs radiate over a wide part of a 360 degree cross section and reflectors are often used to attempt to utilise the otherwise wasted light. Much of the light is lost. As LEd lights can have a larger % of output usefully used this can also be used in statements about "effective output power".

Perceived light power by a user is expressed in lumens and is a measure both of the actual optical power (Watts) and the reponse of a typical human eye. The human eye is most sensitive to a yi=ucky green yellow colour - which is why SOME fire engines are pained this colour [like many of these ones](https://www.google.co.nz/search?hl=en&site=imghp&tbm=isch&source=hp&biw=1920&bih=1081&q=fire+engine&oq=fire+engine&gs_l=img.3..0l10.4973.7685.0.7870.11.7.0.4.4.0.255.911.4j0j3.7.0....0...1ac.1.27.img..2.9.597.2dnSxEvjuo0#hl=en&q=fire+engine+green&tbm=isch) or this:

[image]

Eye response curves:

Dotted line is "low light" sensitivity.
Black bordered solid colour area is eye response as per 1931 standard.
In 1978 the red bordered area at left was added to the curve. NOTE that the left hand "reddish" coloured area is in fact blue-violet!

[image]

---

**Power In / Power Out**

2. In our universe, as far as is known by main stream Science, so far, energy is "conserved". ie energy can neither be created or destroyed in a closed system.

Power is the rate at which energy is provided.
So power into a system at a given moment must equal power out.
 The form the power out takes can vary.
 In a transformer the main power outputs are the desired form (electrical energy), and the incidental byproducts of the process. Mainly:

- Heat - usually 1% to 10% range. (Mostly winding "I^2R" losses, core losses)
- Sound - Only a small amount. Lamination "buzzing".
- Light -  very little indeed except when things go very wrong.
- Electromagnetic radiation - minimal and minimised by design.

Electrical power out and heat are the usual major energy outputs.

Comment: Power in - power out = power being stored in the system ( often 0 )  -- this is both nit picking and important

Comment: I agree it is important, I am working on a system that will put power in and out and store it. I understand what your saying about the lighting It makes sense to me now, that a 11w LED will put out the Lumen's of a 50w bulb. Now this opens up another question. Can there be a primary winding core on a transformer then have 4 different secondary winding  cores. and will the power output from the primary core be divided 4 ways? I am thinking that with a magnetic field that the same amount of power will be transferred to each secondary core. is this incorrect?

Comment: @Morgan - power on a given secondary will depend on its load. You can potentially get all the power from one secondary or divie it evenly or unenvenly or only use 2 of the 4 etc. The magnetic field links al equally. How you load the field is up t you. If youdo take all from one primary the copper losses will be higher than if you had one full sized winding as wire size must god down, resistance must go up and losees are I^2 x R.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon I think I understand what your saying, I just need to wrap my head around it for a moment or two. or four!

Answer (score 3):

Power in a transformer is conserved, except for losses that happen [in a real transformer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformer#The_real_transformer). [In the ideal, lossless transformer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformer#The_ideal_transformer) you have \$V_{primary} x I_{primary} = V_{secondary} x I_{secondary}\$.

From what you have found so far about transformers, you can reach the same conclusion (just give numbers to "low voltage", "high voltage", "low current" and "high current" and do the calculations).

As for your light bulb example, probably your 11 W LED light outputs light that is **equivalent** to a 50 W incandescent light bulb.

Comment: Equivalent to a 50W *incandescent* light bulb, to be specific. In time, such a comparison should be done away with (by manufacturers), lest it confuse people.

Comment: The comparison is sometimes caused by regulation, not only manufacturers.  Power demand of the device had become the consumer measure of light output.  A better measure of light output would be lumens, and some regulatory regimes have moved in that direction.

Comment: thank you Renan, I made a comment in response to both you and another answer, I also asked another question. Your input on it will be appreciated.   Can there be a primary winding core on a transformer then have 4 different secondary winding cores. and will the power output from the primary core be divided 4 ways? I am thinking that with a magnetic field that the same amount of power will be transferred to each secondary core. is this incorrect?